# How to create infinite variables

Tags: python, pickle

I'd like to know if there is a way to make infinite variables. I could not find anything on the web on this so can someone help? I am using python IDEL 3.9.1 on a mac in case that makes a difference. Just to make this clear I don't want to REWRITE variables. I have a pickle file that stores information using repeated variables. I need to read them. Here is my code:

```
json = .json
while loopvariable == true:
    #looping variable here = pickle.load( open( savefilename, "rb"
    if #name (a variable from a input() earlier == #looping variable here: 
        savefilename = #looping variable here + json
        favorite_color = pickle.load( open( savefilename, "rb" 
        loopvariable = false
    elif name != #looping variable here
        a = true
while a = true:
    loopvariable = false
    loopvariable = true
    a = false
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Yes. Someone can help you. Have you tried using a `list` or a `dict`?

Comment: Do you mean infinite variables without an `OutofMemoryError`?

Comment: What's an "infinite variable"?

Comment: Do you mean create an infinite _number_ of variables? As in using a `list` or `dict` to store info? Are you aware of either of those data structures? Can you show an example of how you want the code to look/work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand exactly want to do, but I can give some general advice.

You should **always** use collections data structures when dealing with multiple related pieces of data, rather than storing them in separate variables.

For instance, if trying to input three names from the user, a beginner programmer might just say: "Hey I know I'll use three variables!". This is the *wrong* way to write this code.

I.e.

```
name1 = input('Name: ')
name2 = input('Name: ')
name3 = input('Name: ')
```

Why is this frowned upon? Because then you must access each variable by name, and it is a pain to access them dynamically using an index.

So say you wanted to print all three names out, you would now have to write

```
print(name1)
print(name2)
print(name3)
```

which is a lot of work.

Instead, always use a list or other collection data structure.

For instance here you would usually be better off to write the code like this.

```
names = []
for i in range(3):
    names.append(input('Name: '))

...

for i in range(3):
    print(names[i])
```

---

So this answers your question because it sounds like you are trying to save pieces of data in many many different variables. This makes it not only hard to access the variables, but also a pain to keep track of them. It is also not the intended way that Python was designed (as opposed to other languages like MATLAB, where you may be forced to create variables to keep track of matrices etc.)

Comment: ...I'll explain the situation.

Comment: I'm trying to make a game that you can make infinite save files in, and I'm using pickle to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! Here is my code now:

```
import pickle
names = []
count = 0
times = 1
a = "false"
json = ".json"
gameplayfunc = "false"
while (count < 9):
    for i in range(times):
        names.append(input('Please enter save file name: '))
    x = input("Would you like to create another save file?")
    if x == "Yes" or x == "yes" or x == "YES":
        namee = names[i] + json
        pickle.dump( x, open( namee, "wb" ) )
        times = times + 1
        a == "true"
    elif x == "No" or x == "no" or x == "NO":
        namee = names[i] + json
        pickle.dump( x, open( namee, "wb" ) )
        gameplayfunc = "true"
        count = 10
while a == "true":
    count = 10
    count = 1
    a == false

...


for i in range(times):
    print(names[i])
```

I used a combination of the for i in range + list idea and my own knowledge to create this (sorta) infinite variable generator. It will fit into a situation that requires one, anyway. Thank you guys!

Comment: Apparently, I can't accept mt own answer for 2 days...